# How to add Web API route to filter on different field

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

I am trying to add a route to my MYC 4 Web API application that will return records based on the value of the CompID field rather than the primary key of the table which is EntryID.

My current ResultsController was built as a new scaffold item and so the default GETs are:

```
// GET: api/Results
    public IQueryable<PlayerEntry> GetPlayerEntries()
    {
        return db.PlayerEntries;
    }

    // GET: api/Results/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(PlayerEntry))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPlayerEntry(int id)
    {
        PlayerEntry playerEntry = db.PlayerEntries.Find(id);
        if (playerEntry == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(playerEntry);
    }

    // GET: api/Results/CompID
    [ResponseType(typeof(PlayerEntry))]
    public IHttpActionResult PlayerEntryByCompID(int CompID)
    {
        PlayerEntry playerEntry = db.PlayerEntries.Find(CompID);
        if (playerEntry == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(playerEntry);
    }
```

Can I simply add one of these that would allow me to use a route along the lines of /api/results/compid/1000 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use attribute routing so that the new method is supported. On the contrary, the action selector will have no way to choose between the actions.

The attrbute could be somehting like this:

```
 [Route("api/results/compid/{id}")]
```

However, you need to registre the attribute routes, and understand what you're doing, so, please, read the attribute routing docs from Microsoft: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

*NOTE: there are alternative ways, like naming the parameters with different names and providing the named parameter in the query string or creating routes that require an action name, but the solution proposed is the one which fits your case best*